# How to hide url by react-router, so component should not be visible

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a page which shows all players with a URL: `www.mysite.com/players`, but I like to hide 'players' word from ULR. There should be same result but with URL like `www.mysite.com/`.  Is there any idea to acheive this?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
 <Switch>
 <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
 <Route path="/players" component={Players} />
 <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
 </switch>
```

I only wants to hide word players from URL.  Thanks in advance..

Comment: is homePage different  about the Players

Comment: Yes, homePage is totally different then players. I only want to hide players word from URL..

Comment: do you want you to need 2 pages in same router or one or both   HomePage and Players in the same router, please clear

Comment: no dear, players page is not doing anything with HomePage. They are totally different pages. HomePage is Index page and Players page is another page with different routing, which showing all players. I only wants to hide URL with Players. Even 'www.mysite.com/allPlayersinmyteam'  will be also fine instead of 'www.mysite.com/players'. I only wants to hide the url, that's it.

Comment: what is the URL should be appear to show player  you want

Comment: ideal is 'www.mysite.com/' instead of 'www.mysite.com/players'.   But this is also URL for HomePage.  which actually  confusing me..

Comment: you should be charged the home page to this shape  <Route exact path="/" component={Players} />  and the router of the homepage to another router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control page state you can you these ways:

- routing with path (you don't want to use this)
- hash routing (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter)
- react state (this.setState({ currentPage: 'players }):

```
       switch(this.state.currentPage) {
          case 'players':
            return <PlayersPage />
          default:
            return <IndexPage />
       }
```

In your case I recommend you the third way.